# how the python interpreter find the modules path?

Tags: python, search-path

I'm new to python, and I find that to see the import search paths, you have to import the `sys` module and than access the list of paths using `sys.path`, if this list is not available until I explicitly import the `sys` module, so how the interpreter figure out where this module resides.
thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module search path always exists, even before you import the sys module. The sys module just makes it available for you.

It reflects the contents of the system variable `$PYTHONPATH`, or a system default, if you have not set that environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default search path within the interpreter. (https://docs.python.org/2/install/#modifying-python-s-search-path )

> A default value for the path is configured into the Python binary when the interpreter is built.

BTW, `sys` is built into the Python interpreter. (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules)

> One particular module deserves some attention: `sys`, which is built into every Python interpreter.